# Revoke particular columns in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I've tried using the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-revoke.html) but doesn't seem to help. If you can please give me an example.

```
revoke select (column1, column2) on table from specific_user
```

hasn't worked.

```
Access privileges
 Schema | Name  | Type  |     Access privileges     | Column privileges | Policies 
--------+-------+-------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------
 public | users | table | himanshu=arwdDxt/himanshu+|                   | 
        |       |       | reports_user=r/himanshu   |                   | 
(1 row)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the output of `\z table` run in `psql`.

Comment: I first grant users select to reports_user, then I revoke column1 and column2 with the revoke syntac above. Despite doing that I can still access column1 and column 2 from reports  user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that privileges in SQL are additive, and column privileges and table privileges are different.

Revoking a privilege that you didn't grant before has no effect, and granting `SELECT` on a table is different from granting `SELECT` on all columns.

You should revoke the `SELECT` privilege on the table and grant `SELECT` on all columns except the one where you want to deny access:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON "table" FROM specific_user;
GRANT SELECT (<all columns except "column1" and "column2">)
   ON "table" TO specific_user;
```

Check the result with `\z "table"`.

Comment: Should I enter all column names in ```(<all columns except "column1" and "column2">)``` ? This gives a syntax error at "<" . I have over 60 columns.

Comment: Then enter 58 columns.

Answer (score 2):

@Laurenz's answers is correct. I was however a bit confused with the syntax. Just to clarify:

I have table *public.values*:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|    A    |    B    |    C    |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

If user *peter* is supposed to see only the columns *A* and *B*, the following commands are needed:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON public.values FROM peter;
GRANT SELECT ("A", "B") ON public.values TO peter;
```